# form-vertical style

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use [twitter-bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap) for my project and as you might know the default form alignment is vertical, so the labels are shown above the form-fields. You can add class `form-horizontal` to display the labels next to the form-fields.

I'm building a form which is displayed horizontal, but I want a subset of my form to be vertical-aligned. So I added the class `form-vertical` to that section, but it doesn't change anything.

So I looked in the bootstrap stylesheet and there is no declaration for the `form-vertical` class.

Do you have any suggestions to solve (or workaround) this problem?

Comment: Isn´t it by default "vertical"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened a [ticket](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/5500) on github. I implemented the required CSS in my custom stylesheet:

```
.form-vertical .control-label {
  float: none;
  padding-top: inherit;
  text-align: inherit;
  width: auto;
}
.form-vertical .controls {
  margin-left: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to solve this using `<fieldset>`s and applying the form classes to them like this:

```
<form class="form">
   <!-- vertical fieldset, no extra class needed -->
   <fieldset>
      <legend>Vertical fieldset</legend>
      [ add your form elements ] 
   </fieldset>
   <!-- horizontal fieldset with the extra class -->
   <fieldset class="form-horizontal">
      <legend>Horizontal fieldset</legend>
      [ add your form elements ] 
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

Should work with `<div>`s or any other container as well.

Comment: I could workaround with this, but it was easier for me to implement the missing `form-vertical` class. I now don't need to divide the form in multiple fieldsets. But it like the idea of it.